# Compare some columns from 2 csv files using python

Tags: python, csv

Input is 2 `csv` files

```
EID MolIdx TEStart TEEnd TE TZone TBulkBE TBulkAE MC JT zavg vabs vzavg  xyd.x xyd.y xydist nnbw vabsprev midhb
0 370 36700 36800 110 20 36150 37090 0 0 -8.25705 0.219113 -0.000800014 20.8926 41.4347 5.75852 0 4.13067 0 
1 423 17950 18150 210 180 17400 18430 1 0 -4.26426 0.586578 -0.053 77.22 85.2104 22.0534 0 3.551 0 
2 468 41790 42020 240 50 41360 42380 0 0 7.82681 0.181248 -0.00269566 90.0646 92.7698 5.0841 0 4.19304 0
```

and

```
EID MolIdx TEStart TEEnd TE TZone TBulkBE TBulkAE MC JT zavg vabs vzavg xyd.x xyd.y xydist nnbw vabsprev midhb
0 370 36700 36800 110 20 36150 37090 0 0 -0.846655 0.0218695 2.59898e-05 2.0724 4.1259 0.583259 10 0.412513 0 
1 423 17950 18150 210 180 17400 18780 1 0 -0.453311 0.058732 -0.00526783 7.7403 8.52544 2.19627 0 0.354126 0 
2 468 41790 42020 240 70 41360 42380 0 0 0.743716 0.0181613 -0.000256186 9.08777 9.21395 0.502506 0 0.419265 0
```

I need to compare columns `MC` and `JT` from `file1` with this columns from `file2`

Desire output:

```
Number_of_strings
```

Print strings, where values are different

```
import csv

old = csv.reader(open('old.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
row1 = old.next()
new = csv.reader(open('new.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
row2 = new.next()

if (row1[8] == row2[8]) and (row1[9] == row2[9]):
    continue
else:
    print row1[0] + ':' + row1[8] + '!=' + row2[8]
```

But it does't work for me

Comment: You're not looping over all the rows as you're only calling the `next`method on each csv-reader instance *once*. You're missing a looping construct. Other than that, it's not clear at all whether the lines should correspond to the same lines (i.e. line numbers) in the other file. Can perhaps the 3rd linein the first file match the 2nd line in the last file? Please extend your question by giving a clearer description of the desired output.

Comment: How are your files actually delimited? Also  `if row1[8]  != row2[8]) or row1[9] != row2[9]:print(row1[0] + ':' + row1[8] + '!=' + row2[8])` will replace your current logic

Comment: I was wrong. The delimeter is `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- delimiter is  instead of `,`
- you forgot to use a `for` loop to iterate over the rest of the files:

code:

```
import csv

old = csv.reader(open('old.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ')
row1 = old.next()
new = csv.reader(open('new.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ')
row2 = new.next()

for row1, row2 in zip(old, new):
    if (row1[8] == row2[8]) and (row1[9] == row2[9]):
        continue
    else:
        print row1[0] + ':' + row1[8] + '!=' + row2[8]
```

Comment: It returns number of strings, but after some string it print `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: And I compare `JT` and `MC`. Can I `output` `2: JT`, I mean that in 2 string `JT from file1 != JT from file2` print it

Comment: the `IndexError` is probably because some rows contain fewer than 10 columns, you can add a check to skip these rows. I don't understand what you mean by output `2: JT` though

Comment: i have in this file last string `Total_jt:8, total_jt_filt:8, dtreal:76960, Box avg:101.963 101.963 72.8307`, how can I compare columns to this file? 
When it comes to this line the process is finish?

Comment: sounds like you need to run a different comparison for the last line. in this case, you can run the comparison at the end of your script. the last line of each file should be conveniently available in `row1` and `row2` after the `for` loop.